# Variance of a set of quaternions?

Tags: quaternions, variance, density-function

I'm trying to figure out how to express the variance of a set of quaternions that are symmetric around $0.$ Therefore I know that $\operatorname{Var}(w) = \operatorname E(|w|^2)$ with $w=r+xi+yj+zk$ and $\operatorname E(|w|^2) =\int_R |x|^2f(x) \, dx$. Nonetheless, $f(x)$ has four DOF (independent) in the case of quaternions. So how to solve this ?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: If you know only that the distribution is symmetric about $0,$ that's not enough to conclude that the four degrees of freedom are probabilistically independent.

Comment: You wrote $\int_R.$ What is the set $R$? Is it supposed to be the set of all quaternions? $\qquad$

Comment: You need $\displaystyle \operatorname E(|w^2|) = \int_\text{domain} |x|^2 f(x)\,dx$ rather than $\displaystyle \operatorname E(|w^2|) = \int_\text{domain} x^2 f(x)\,dx. \qquad$

Comment: Yes thanks you for the mistake. R is supposed to represent $-\infty$ and $\infty$. Since all the four parts of the quaternion can go from $-\infty$ to $\infty$

Comment: Are these, by any chance, actually *unit* quaternions?

Comment: Saying "$R$ is supposed to represent $-\infty$ and $\infty$" is meaningless because you said $R$ is "a set of quaternions" and there are no quaternions called $\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Comment: Unfortunately, they are not unit quaternions. I just wanted to say that every part of the quaternions that are in the set could go from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.